# Can I create two custom keyboards on one container app

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, custom-keyboard, ios-extensions

I'm trying to create a container app that holds two custom keyboards. 
I have already developed the first keyboard. When I added the second keyboard extension I didn't get any errors, but after compiling only the first keyboard appeared.
Is there a way that I can present two custom keyboards on one container app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. by adding another target you can create another custom keyboard on the same container app